# ANTLR4 not processing UTF-16 input correctly

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR 4.10.1 and C++. I'm using ANTLRInputStream as the input to my lexer

`antlr4::ANTLRInputStream inputStream(....);`

Which works fine until I use UTF-16 characters in the input, as they cause problems later on.

Since ANTLRInputStream is deprecated for 4.10.1, it seems CharStreams needs to be used to be able to specify a Charset, i.e. "UTF-16LE". But I could only find documentation for Java. Is there a way to use CharStreams with UTF-16 to make this work in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input stream in the C++ runtime actually expects UTF-8, always! See also the source code in [`ANTLRInputStream::load`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/ANTLRInputStream.cpp#L42). Internally it converts that to UTF-32. The 16 bit transformation format is never used.

Because of this convention, there's no need to deprecate the C++ version of the `ATNLRInputStream`. That was only necessary for old language targets, which had no UTF-32 (like JS and Java). With that in mind you can ignore the new `CharStreams` class in the C++ target.